# How to pass the content of a cell in DataGridView_CellClick function to button_Click function in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to delete a row in a table -which is shown in dataGridView1- by pressing a button (btnPersonnelDelete) in my form.
The DeleteQuery needs the PersonnelID (perID) as an input in order to function.
The perID is retrieved by "dataGridView1_CellClick" function.

How can I pass the perID to "btnPersonnelDelete_Click" function.
Or if there is another way which makes more sense I'll be glad to follow that.

Thank you in advance.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            long perID;
            // Only if data cells are clicked and not the column names
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                // Gets the PersonnelID which is in column[3] of each row as a string
                string SperID = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                // Check if the string is empty
                if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(SperID)))
                {
                    // Converts PersonnelID from string to long
                    perID = long.Parse(SperID);
                    MessageBox.Show(SperID);                    
                }                
            }            
        }
```

---

```
    private void btnPersonnelDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what should be here?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for deleting row from DataGridView you need the row index or the row itself. deleting by row index is much easier so first of all define a global property to store the index and for executing the DeleteQuery another global property to store personnelID.
It means:

```
int rowIndex=0;//stroe the row index
string perId=String.Empty//store the PersonnelID or 'long' whatever 
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        long perID;
        // Only if data cells are clicked and not the column names
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            // Gets the PersonnelID which is in column[3] of each row as a string
            perId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            rowIndex = e.RowIndex; // store the selected row index
            // Check if the string is empty
            if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(SperID)))
            {
                // Converts PersonnelID from string to long
                perID = long.Parse(perId);
                MessageBox.Show(perId);                    
            }                
        }            
    }
```

on button clicking event:

```
private void btnPersonnelDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Executing delete query by perId

        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);//delete from dataGridview
        dataGridView1.Refresh(); // Redraw dataGridView to delete the row from screen
    }
```

I hope this solution solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you so much. However I wanted to delete the record from the table not just the dataGridView. I declared a string "SperID" then I used it in MyTableAdapter.DeleteQuery(SperID).